# How do I extract a picture from the current picture in Java?

Tags: java, image

I've been assigned a task of having to write code that will extract a picture from the current picture. I've done some research and I found out that something called 'BufferedImage' is what I need to use in order to complete this task, however, I was never taught on how to use this so I thought that I may ask for some help/tips, especially if this is not what I actually need to use. I am currently working in IntelliJ.

Actual task: 
Write a method called extract in the Picture class and its JavaDocs. The method should extract from the current picture a new picture that is defined by the top left hand coordinates (x, y) of the area to be extracted, the width and height of the area. Your method should pass the test contained in the extractTests class.

Picture class:

```
public Picture(int width, int height) {
// let the parent class handle this width and height
super(width, height);
}

/**
* Constructor that takes a picture and creates a
* copy of that picture
*/
public Picture(Picture copyPicture) {
// let the parent class do the copy
super(copyPicture);
}

/**
* Constructor that takes a buffered image
*
* @param image the buffered image to use
*/
public Picture(BufferedImage image) {
super(image);
}

////////////////////// methods ///////////////////////////////////////

/**
* Method to return a string with information about this picture.
*
* @return a string with information about the picture such as fileName,
* height and width.
*/
public String toString() {
String output = "Picture, filename " + getFileName() +
" height " + getHeight()
+ " width " + getWidth();
return output;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
FileChooser.setMediaPath("mediasources/");
String fileName = FileChooser.getMediaPath("butterfly1.jpg");
Picture pictObj = new Picture(fileName);
pictObj.explore();
}
}
```

Test class:

```
public class n extractTests {
@Test
public void comparePicturesTest1() {
FileChooser.setMediaPath("mediasources/");
String fileName = FileChooser.getMediaPath("butterfly1.jpg");
Picture pictObj = new Picture(fileName);
Picture out = pictObj.extract(30, 240, 100, 100);
String fileName3 = FileChooser.getMediaPath("extract2.jpg");
out.write(fileName3);
String fileName1 = FileChooser.getMediaPath("extract1.jpg");
Picture pict2 = new Picture(fileName1);
String fileName2 = FileChooser.getMediaPath("extract2.jpg");
Picture pict3 = new Picture(fileName2);
comparePictures(pict2, pict3);
}

@Test
public void comparePicturesTest2() {
FileChooser.setMediaPath("mediasources/");
String fileName = FileChooser.getMediaPath("butterfly2.jpg");
Picture pictObj = new Picture(fileName);
Picture out = pictObj.extract(80, 50, 400, 300);
String fileName3 = FileChooser.getMediaPath("extract4.jpg");
out.write(fileName3);
String fileName1 = FileChooser.getMediaPath("extract3.jpg");
Picture pict2 = new Picture(fileName1);
String fileName2 = FileChooser.getMediaPath("extract4.jpg");
Picture pict3 = new Picture(fileName2);
comparePictures(pict2, pict3);
}

private void comparePictures(Picture pict2, Picture pict3) {
Pixel[] pixels1 = pict2.getPixels();
Pixel[] pixels2 = pict3.getPixels();
assertEquals(pixels1.length, pixels2.length);
for(int i = 0; i < pixels1.length; i++) {
Pixel pixel1 = pixels1[i];
Pixel pixel2 = pixels2[i];
assertEquals("At pixel (" + pixel1.getX() + ", " + pixel1.getY() + ")",
pixel1.getColor(), pixel2.getColor());
}
}
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: JavaDOcs are your friend, see [`BufferedImage#getSubImage`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getSubimage-int-int-int-int-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extracting a new picture from the current picture](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34007202/extracting-a-new-picture-from-the-current-picture)